# r loess: coefficients of global "parametric" terms

Tags: r, coefficients, loess

Is there a way how I can extract coefficients of globally fitted terms in local regression modeling?

Maybe I do misunderstand the role of globally fitted terms in the function loess, but what I would like to have is the following:

```
# baseline:
x <- sin(seq(0.2,0.6,length.out=100)*pi)

# noise:
x_noise <- rnorm(length(x),0,0.1)

# known structure:
x_1 <- sin(seq(5,20,length.out=100))

# signal:
y <- x + x_1*0.25 + x_noise

# fit loess model:
x_seq <- seq_along(x)
mod <- loess(y ~ x_seq + x_1,parametric="x_1")
```

The fit is done perfectly, however, how can I extract the estimated value of the globally fitted term `x_1` (i.e. some value near 0.25 for the example above)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to my problem using the function `gam` from the package `gam`:

```
require(gam)
mod2 <- gam(y ~ lo(x_seq,span=0.75,degree=2) + x_1)
```

However, the fits from the two models are not exactly the same (which might be due to different control settings?)...